# JBOSS throws exception on startup

Tags: jboss, jms, startup

I'm starting jboss server through CLI in windows 7. Initially it was starting but then I wrote java code for sending messages to learn JMS. After that I'm getting below exceptions. Could anyone please help me in resolving this.

Note: I've removed java file(Consumer.java) from my system, still somehow exception shows it's referring to my java file.

```
17:52:18,845 INFO  [org.jboss.as.deployment.connector] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS010401: Bound JCA ConnectionFactory [java:/JmsXA]
17:52:18,902 INFO  [org.jboss.as.messaging] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS011601: Bound messaging object to jndi name java:/topic/test
17:52:19,270 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "Consumer.java"
17:52:19,318 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-7) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."Consumer.java".STRUCTURE
: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."Consumer.java".STRUCTURE: Failed to process phase STRUCTURE of deployment "Consumer.java"
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:119) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Fin
al]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: Failed to mount deployment content
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.module.DeploymentRootMountProcessor.deploy(DeploymentRootMountProcessor.java:91) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.ja
r:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Fin
al]
        ... 5 more
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:215) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:153) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:117) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
        at org.jboss.vfs.spi.JavaZipFileSystem.<init>(JavaZipFileSystem.java:97) [jboss-vfs-3.1.0.Final.jar:3.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.vfs.spi.JavaZipFileSystem.<init>(JavaZipFileSystem.java:83) [jboss-vfs-3.1.0.Final.jar:3.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.vfs.VFS.mountZip(VFS.java:408) [jboss-vfs-3.1.0.Final.jar:3.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.vfs.VFS.mountZip(VFS.java:434) [jboss-vfs-3.1.0.Final.jar:3.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentMountProvider$Factory$ServerDeploymentRepositoryImpl.mountDeploymentContent(DeploymentMountProvider.ja
va:95) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.module.DeploymentRootMountProcessor.deploy(DeploymentRootMountProcessor.java:87) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.ja
r:7.1.1.Final]
        ... 6 more

17:52:19,488 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "Consumer.java" was rolled back with failure mes
sage {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"Consumer.java\".STRUCTURE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.depl
oyment.unit.\"Consumer.java\".STRUCTURE: Failed to process phase STRUCTURE of deployment \"Consumer.java\""}}
17:52:19,492 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment Consumer.java in 4ms
17:52:19,517 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."Consumer.java".STRUCTURE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in servic
e jboss.deployment.unit."Consumer.java".STRUCTURE: Failed to process phase STRUCTURE of deployment "Consumer.java"

17:52:19,529 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
17:52:19,544 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) {"JBAS014653: Composite operation failed and was rolled back.
Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" => {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"Consumer.java\".STRUCTURE" => "org.jboss.msc.ser
vice.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"Consumer.java\".STRUCTURE: Failed to process phase STRUCTURE of deployment \"Consumer.java\""}}}}
17:52:19,550 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015875: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" started (with errors) in 5704ms - Started 171 of 251
 services (1 services failed or missing dependencies, 78 services are passive or on-demand)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I've come across this problem when deploying an ear file that contained an empty jar (view the contents and order by size). Check your ear file for an empty jar, if it contains one remove it.

Regards,
Saz

---